# Why won't epson et-3750 print multiple copies from ubuntu 20.04 lts but will in ubuntu 18. Ubuntu for amd 64bit, deb drivers

Tags: drivers, printing, 20.04

Before I upgraded to 20.04, (fresh install from live cd, on new blank hdd ) my epson et-3750 printer was quite happy printing any number of copies I requested from ubuntu 18lts. But after the upgrade, it will only print 1 copy at a time.
In the print queue, under status, it says processing-printer error. It prints one page, then queue is empty.

I have tried several epson dl drivers, all amd64bit, deb, and all react the same.
I also follow the instruction from epson to do commands from  term before installing drivers. Driver install seems normal.

This happens on main pc with printer connected usb, and also fails on 2nd similar pc using printer on network to 1st pc.

I also have a brother hll 2340d printer which has none of these issues.

Sure hope someone here has a solution for me.
Thanks,
st

Comment: can i find out from a moderator why this question isnt getting any solutions? am i asking wrong, or in wrong place? thx, st

Comment: I have the same problem, with a Brother MFC printer, which was bulletproof otherwise.  Very strange, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem (I had a new install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) by downloading the drivers from the Brother site.  In looking at the original automatic install of the printer, it shows up in the printer list, but as 'driverless'.   After installing, the printer shows up as a 'CUPS' printer, and it can print multiple copies.